# Assign static public IP to HAProxy on AKS for egress traffic

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, haproxy, azure-aks

There is some documentation around how to set up a public static IP to a Kubernetes service on AKS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/egress). I have an AKS cluster where the traffic goes through an HAProxy ingress controller so I can't assign an IP to the service (which is of type ClusterIP) as described in the documentation. I was wondering how I can assign a public static IP to the egress traffic using HAProxy.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change from `type: ClusterIP` to `type: LoadBalancer`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: IP
  type: LoadBalancer
```

NOTE: You can create the the PublicIP in advance. AKS and the Service will create a LoadBalancer for you.